# How to add name in email headers using aws ses

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Below is my code to send email using aws ses using nodejs.

```
ses.sendEmail( { 
           Source: sails.config.myconf.aws.emailFrom, 
           Destination: { ToAddresses: [useObj.email]},
           Message: {
               Subject:{
                  Data: subject
               },
               Body: {
                   Html: {
                       Data: template,
                   }
                }
           }
        });
```

It will work see attached image below[image]
but it show contact as name. Instead of this i want to add client name there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [amazon-ses How can set name for email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141041/amazon-ses-how-can-set-name-for-email)

Comment: i already checked this link and tried accepted answer but it wont work.

Comment: You need to explain specifically what "it won't work" means.  The solution in the referenced answer is correct -- you set the sending address to a string like `"Sender Name" <address@example.com>`.  If that doesn't work, then please explain in what way it fails.

Comment: Source: 'John Doe <abc@xyz.com>',  I tried by using this and it gives errors

Answer (score 7):

Can you try sails.config.myconf.aws.emailFrom to be like

```
Sachin Sharma < sachin@enraiser.com >
```

[reference 1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=218579)

Comment: i tried  MailFromDomain: 'clientName',  it wont work. It says Unexpected key 'MailFromDomain' found in params.  Do you know exact key to be used?

Answer (score 3):

You can set name is source (Source: "App Name!! app_email@example.com"). Example below

```
{
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["example@example.com"]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Data: "YOUR MESSAGE"
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: "YOUR SUBJECT"
        }
    },
    Source: "App Name!! <from_email@example.com>"
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Source: '"ABC Group" <'+sails.config.myconf.aws.emailFrom+'>';
```

Above code solve my problem.

Comment: Also tell , how it is different from what I proposed.  logically I proposed the same thing.  missing  quote here and there does not make it a different answer. Instead of posting new answer you should have just corrected my answer.